# Push different values into sub documents with different conditions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sql-update

I have the following documents:

```json
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "items": [] 
}, {
    "_id": 2,
    "items": []
}]
```

I want to push "item1.1" to document where `_id == 1`, and "item2.1" to document where `_id == 2`. After the operation, the document should be as follows:

```json
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "items": ["item1.1"] 
}, {
    "_id": 2,
    "items": ["item2.1"]
}]
```

Is there any way to push these values in a **single** update query?

---

I found that we can use bulkWrite to do this in this similar question [Update many documents in mongoDB with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023520/update-many-documents-in-mongodb-with-different-values).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `$push` update option.

**Example: To update for `_id` 1:**

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1  // Match Condition
},
{
  "$push": {
    "items": "item1.1"  // Update value
  }
});
```

**Example: To update for `_id` 2:**

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 2  // Match Condition
},
{
  "$push": {
    "items": "item2.1"  // Update value
  }
});
```

If you want to update with the first document of the collection, there is no other way than to find by skip and limit, and update.

```
var firstDoc = db.collection.find({}).skip(0).limit(1)
db.collection.update({
  "_id": firstDoc["_id"]  // Match Condition
},
{
  "$push": {
    "items": "item1.1"  // Update value
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there possible to push "item1.1" where _id==1 and "item2.1" where _id==2 in a single update query?

Comment: Yes, that's my first example. Change the `_id` in the `Match Condition` block to `1` or `2` to update for the corresponding document. I will update by answer shortly for both `1` and `2` examples

Comment: In this way, we have to execute two update queries with condition `_id==1` and `_id==2`, respectively.  Maybe we can use bulkWrite to execute one single update query?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There is no way to perform these in a single update command. Go for BulkWrite operation if more docs have to be updated, to reduce round trip.